# shell script for awk print divide value with 1024

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to do some arthimatic operations on awk output process. 
my sample file contains string and it's count. Now i am trying to make the count values to be in format of MB (defualt count will come in bytes.)

Example :
       myfile.txt

```
   a 123455
   b 34455566
   c 10394934839
   d 102445555
```

my script :

```
  cat myfile.txt | while read line; do name=$line ; name=`echo $fname|awk '{print   $1}'` ; cnt=`echo $fname|awk '{print $1}'`; if [$cnt -gt 1024] ; then echo "$name value in critical $cnt";fi done
```

Problem: I want the cnt value should be convert into MB ( cnt/1024/1024) .

no clue how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this (pure Bash):

```
$ cat myfile.txt | while read l f ; do echo $l $((f/1024/1024)) ;if [ $((f/1024/1024)) -gt 
1024 ] ; then echo "$l value in critical ";fi done
a 0
b 32
c 9913
c value in critical 
d 97
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it directly in `awk` without looping in `BASH`:

```
awk '{print $1, $2/(1024*1024)}' file
a 0.117736
b 32.8594
c 9913.38
d 97.6997
```

OR for 2 decimal point output:

```
awk '{printf "%s %.2f\n", $1, $2/(1024*1024)}' file
a 0.12
b 32.86
c 9913.38
d 97.70
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kent$  awk '{printf "%s %.2f\n",$1,$2/1024/1024}' file
a 0.12
b 32.86
c 9913.38
d 97.70
```

change the `%.2f` to gain different precision.

if you want to add the critical check:

```
awk '{v=$2/1024/1024;printf "%s %.2f%s\n",$1,v,(v>1024?" <=critical":"")}' file
a 0.12
b 32.86
c 9913.38 <=critical
d 97.70
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have structured data and you want to loop per line, just use `awk`. Besides the saving of CPU cycles (which is negligible in most cases) the biggest benefit is that you avoid the weird quote and space moaning of Bash.

```
awk '{ MB = int($2/1024/1024); print $1 " " MB; if (MB > 1024) print $1 " value in critical"}' myfile.txt
```

Output:

```
a 0
b 32
c 9913
c value in critical
d 97
```

Breaking it down:

```
MB = int($2/1024/1024)    ->    Take the value in the second field ($2).
                                Make it into an integer (to round the number)
                                and store it in the variable MB.

print $1 " " MB           ->    Print the first field ($1), followed by
                                a space, and finally the value in MB.

if (MB > 1024)
    print $1 " val.."     ->    If MB < 1024, print first field followed by msg.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk way

```
awk '{$2/=2^20}1' file
```

Formatted

```
awk '$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2/2^20)' file
```

With crit

```
awk '$2=sprintf("%.2f%s",x=($2/2^20),x>1024?" [critical]":"")' test
```